# How do I create a semi draggable recyclerview on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My question is simple but the implementation is being really tricky on Android. I am wondering how may I drag only the "draggable part", which are the items below the headers.

[image: recyclerview table with categories]

I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) to implement the drag feature. But how may I differentiate between a Header ViewHolder and an Item ViewHolder while dragging?

Adapter class is listed below

```
public class ColorRecyclerViewAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ColorRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolderSelector> implements TouchCallbackHelperAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> mItems;
    private final HelperOnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;
    private ItemViewHolderSelector oldHolder;

    public ColorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, HelperOnStartDragListener dragStartListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mItems = data;
        this.mDragStartListener = dragStartListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        mItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(final int fromPosition, final int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                Collections.swap(mItems, i, i + 1);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                Collections.swap(mItems, i, i - 1);
            }
        }
        mDragStartListener.onFinishDrag(null);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        mItems.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(mItems.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolderSelector onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.color_recycler_view_item_drag_mode, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolderSelector(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemViewHolderSelector holder, final int position) {
        final String item = mItems.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(item);
        holder.drag.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(holder);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems != null ? mItems.size() : 0;
    }

    class ItemViewHolderSelector extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements HelperViewHolderSelector {

        private TextView name;
        private ImageView drag;
        private View itemView;

        ItemViewHolderSelector(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            drag = itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_recycler_view_drag);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.color_recycler_view_name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Based on @fernandospr answer, I've created a repository with the final code. You can [access it here](https://github.com/DimasDark/header_recycler_view-).

Answer (score 2):

The `RecyclerView` just shows the views you create on the `onCreateViewHolder`.

Depending on your position, you'll need to create different views. This means that you'll create a `HeaderViewHolder` when the position corresponds to a header and an `ItemViewHolder` when the position corresponds to an item.

So you'll have to refactor your `ColorRecyclerViewAdapter` to:

```
private static final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
private static final int ITEM_VIEW = 1;

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolderSelector onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == ITEM_VIEW) {
       ...
       return new ItemViewHolderSelector(view);
    } else {
       ...
       return new HeaderViewHolderSelector(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   if (ITEM_VIEW == holder.getItemViewType()) {
      ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return itemsCount + headersCount;
}
```

Inside the `onBindViewHolder` you should only allow an item to drag by setting the TouchListener.

Also, inside the `onMove` and and `onSwiped` methods you should use the position to know if it is a header or an item and allow or not the execution:

```
@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
   if (isItemPosition(position)) { 
      ...
   }
}

@Override
public boolean onItemMove(final int fromPosition, final int toPosition) {
   if (isItemPosition(position)) { 
      ...
   }
}
```

The `isItemPosition()` is a method you'll need to write that depends on how the adapter holds the items and headers data.